# custom controllers for camelCase collection types in strapi

Tags: strapi

I've created a bunch of collections in strapi using cammelCase:
[image]

However, this created the following file structure:
`/api/class-resource/controllers/class-resource.js`

Now, when I try to follow [this guide](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/guides/is-owner.html#introduction) to create a custom controller, the js compiler won't let me call the service I need because it thinks I'm subtracting:

```js
module.exports = {
  /**
   * Create a record.
   *
   * @return {Object}
   */

  async create(ctx) {
    let entity;
    if (ctx.is('multipart')) {
      const { data, files } = parseMultipartData(ctx);
      data.author = ctx.state.user.id;
      entity = await strapi.services.class-resource.create(data, { files });  //problem here
    } else {
      ctx.request.body.author = ctx.state.user.id;
      entity = await strapi.services.class-resource.create(ctx.request.body); //problem here
    }
    return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.class-resource}); //problem here
  },
};
```

is there any way around this, other than renaming all my content types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution was given to me by Pascal Isman in the strapi community slack:
`strapi.services['camel-case'].create(...)`

Comment: Link so we could get some understanding of context?

Answer (score 0):

I used the Joey code to replace findOne per ID by slug
seem to work

/controllers

```
const { sanitizeEntity } = require("strapi-utils");

module.exports = {
  async findOne(ctx) {
    const { slug } = ctx.params;

    const entity = await strapi.services["blog-post"].findOne({ slug });
    return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models["blog-post"] });
  },
};
```

/config

```
{
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/blog-posts/:slug",
      "handler": "blog-post.findOne",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
```